# I can't figure out, how real app looks like?

Tags: redux

I read some rules that Redux based on, at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54846305/1109741), and Todo example. But I still not understand it. Let's see how Skype like project, looks like. I supposed that every state variable, even view options is placed in this central store, as well, all chat thread and so on. and every reducer call, return new fresh copy for all. beside all old previous state.

Did I should duplicate all data represents: Tabs, availability flags, profiles, view options, chat message list for each member (users). etc. for each action, like:

1. Chat coming
2. Scroll up chat pane toward last year
3. Availability change
4. View option changes
5. Change tab (Favorites, Recent chat..)
6. Change to another user

I not sure somebody meant to do that. And what we do about app with 30000 record placed on grid. we hold one copy for every action result state, like field update? or even it's there just new state of view, like scrolling one line? or change the column view order?

Also in this way, I think it's more difficult to detriment what part of UI need redraw?

Comment: the root reducer normally consists of many other reducers and one action normally only calls one or a few of the reducers. so only certain properties on the store object are updated. you asked multiple questions and it is really hard to understand what you actually mean. you should probably take some time and rewrite your question with a minimal example.

Comment: Ok, in short, when I have thread of 1000 chat messages on the screen. The reducer of delete action, return new list with new copy for each single item? or it's return a single message flagged as deleted? or maybe it's return arrays of pointers to original messages objects?